# Threaded application writing duplicate lines to log file

Tags: java, regex, multithreading

I have written a multithreaded application that analyzes rows in a database with regex and updates them appropriately. I am writing each row to a log file for logging purposes. I have noticed that the same row is being written to the log file several times...sometimes upwards of 15 times. Here are snippets of the code.

Setting up ThreadPoolExecuter:

```
private static BlockingQueue<Runnable> worksQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(blockingQueueSize);
private static ThreadPoolExecutor exec = new ThreadPoolExecutor(threadPoolSize, threadPoolSize, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, worksQueue);
```

In this part, I run a query, then go through the results:

```
rs = ps.executeQuery();

while (rs.next()) {
    exec.execute(new UpdateMember(rs, conn, fileWriter));

    if (worksQueue.size() == blockingQueueSize) {
        //reach the maximum, stop refill
        for (;;) {
            Thread.yield();
            //wait until the size of queue reached the minimum  
            if (worksQueue.size() == 0) {
                //start refill
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UpdateMember (with only run and writeToLog methods showing):

```
public class UpdateMember implements Runnable {

    ResultSet rs;
    Connection conn;
    FileWriter fw;

    public UpdateMember(ResultSet rs, Connection conn, FileWriter fw) {
        this.rs = rs;
        this.conn = conn;
        this.fw = fw;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            String regex = "((?<city>[a-zA-Z\\s\\.]+)\\s)?(?<provState>AB|ALB|Alta|alberta|BC|B\\.C\\.|British Columbia|LB|Labrador|MB|Man|Manitoba|N[BLTSU]|Nfld|NF|Newfoundland|NWT|Northwest Territories|Nova Scotia|New Brunswick|Nunavut|ON|ONT|Ontario|PE|PEI|Prince Edward Island|QC|PC|QUE|QU|Quebec|SK|Sask|Saskatchewan|YT|Yukon|Yukon Territories)(\\s(?<country>CA|CAN|CANADA))?$";
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

            BigDecimal memrecno = rs.getBigDecimal(2);
            String addressLineTwo = rs.getString(4);
            String addressLineThree = rs.getString(5);
            String addressLineFour = rs.getString(6);
            BigDecimal attrrecno = rs.getBigDecimal(9);

            String addressBeingParsed = "";
            String city = null;
            String province = null;
            String country = null;

            boolean usingAddressThree = false;
            boolean usingAddressFour = false;

            if (addressLineFour == null) {
                if (addressLineThree == null) {
                    city = "Unknown";
                }
                else
                {
                    addressBeingParsed = addressLineThree;
                    usingAddressThree = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                addressBeingParsed = addressLineFour;
                usingAddressFour = true;
            }

            if (usingAddressThree || usingAddressFour) {
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(addressBeingParsed);

                // if matches are found
                if (matcher.matches()) {
                    city = matcher.group("city");
                    province = matcher.group("provState");
                    country = matcher.group("country");

                    if (city == null || city.isEmpty()) {
                        // cities are alpha characters and spaces only
                        String cityRegex = "(?<city>^[a-zA-Z\\s\\.]+$)";
                        Pattern cityPattern = Pattern.compile(cityRegex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

                        if (usingAddressFour && (addressLineThree != null) && !addressLineThree.isEmpty()) {
                            Matcher cityMatcher = cityPattern.matcher(addressLineThree);
                            if (cityMatcher.matches()) {
                                city = cityMatcher.group("city");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                city = "Unknown";
                            }
                        }
                        else if (usingAddressThree && (addressLineTwo != null) && !addressLineTwo.isEmpty()) {
                            Matcher cityMatcher = cityPattern.matcher(addressLineTwo);
                            if (cityMatcher.matches()) {
                                city = cityMatcher.group("city");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                city = "Unknown";
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            city = "Unknown";
                        }
                    }

                    if (province != null && !province.isEmpty()) {
                        province = createProvinceCode(province);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    city = "Unknown";
                }
            }

            // update attributes in database
            boolean success = updateRow(memrecno, attrrecno, city, province);

            String logLine = memrecno.toString() + "|" + attrrecno.toString() + "|" + addressLineTwo + "|" + addressLineThree + "|" + addressLineFour + "|" + city + "|" + province + "|" + country + "|" + success + "|" + String.valueOf(Thread.currentThread().getId());

            writeToLog(logLine);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private synchronized void writeToLog(String line) {
        try {
            fw.write(line + "\r\n");
            fw.flush();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error writing to log file. " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if the threads are also calling the updateRow method multiple times, but I'm assuming they are and that's really bad.

Any ideas as to why it would be doing this?

Comment: It looks like you may have multiple threads in `writeToLog()` unless it synchronized. Have you tried synchronizing it?

Comment: Sorry I should have shared the writeToLog() method. I updated my question to include it. It is synchronized.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think ResultSet is thread safe. From your code, you should get the value first and then pass the value instead of rs into the thread.

Comment: Thanks...seems like you're right. ResultSet is not thread safe. Neither is Statement or PreparedStatement. Can I create a new ResultSet object and assign it to rs? Or will I get issues because it's passing by reference?

Comment: I am not sure why you must pass the ResultSet into the executor, cos ResultSet only has cursor to the data in the database. You can use Object[] to keep the value and then pass it into the thread. If u want to use the resultset to update the data in database, I think a good solution is to distribute your query condition to different threads which can use the result set of themselves.